# Server setup for 2 webservers

Tags: apache, iis

I have a HTTPS website hosted by IIS. In this site I embed another HTPPS website within a iframe. The content of this iframe is hosted by Apache. Both servers, IIS and Apache, are on the same server.

1. Do we need to have the same SSL certificates on both webservers?
2. The first listens on port 8443 and the second one on port 443. Do we need to separate public IPs? Is there another way to root internally?
3. How would be the proper setup having two different webservers (IIS, embeded Apache) and only one external IP?

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to have the same SSL certificates on both webservers?

No, you could bind different SSL certifcate if you bind different domain for your IIS or apache server.

> The first listens on port 8443 and the second one on port 443. Do we need to separate public IPs? Is there another way to root internally?

No, we access the site by using the same ip with different ports.

> How would be the proper setup having two different webservers (IIS, embeded Apache) and only one external IP?

In my opinion, the only things is that you should make sure the port is free for each web server.

For example, if IIS use 80, the Apache couldn't use 80.